# attach certificate with web service request in java

Tags: java

I have to create client code for soap web service in java.which has input as basic authentication and ssl certificate. I couldn't find way to attach certificate with post request.Can you tell me how to attach certificate and password with Post request

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache CXF, this code might help you:

```
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(service);
    HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

    TLSClientParameters tlsConfig = new TLSClientParameters();
    try {
        //Set up the keyStore for CXF
        InputStream keyStoreInputStream = new FileOrClasspathResource(keyStorePath).openStream();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustFactory.init(keyStore);
        TrustManager[] tm = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();
        tlsConfig.setTrustManagers(tm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Couldn't initialize keyStore with name " + keyStorePath, e);
    }

    httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsConfig);
```